# Delete a file with specific name and dynamic file extension

Tags: c#

How can I search an existing file with dynamic file extension and delete it via Regex?

```
var reg = new Regex(@"\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp");
```

I can provide file name but I don't know file extension exactly.

Ex: `string fileName = "img01";`. I wanna delete these images: `img01.jpg`, `img01.jpeg`, `img01.png`, `img01.gif`, `img01.bmp`.

Can you give me a sample to do this?

p/s: I don't want to get all files with specific extension in folder and use a loop to delete it.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us how to delete multiple files without a loop.

Comment: `I don't want to get all files with specific extension in folder and use a loop to delete it.` - You can hide it behind some nifty LINQ query, inside a method, or else. But in the end, looping is how you have to do it.

Comment: That `p/s` part - You want to hardcode everything? Eventually you **will** need to use looping some way or the other.

Comment: You can check out the [`System.IO.File.Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method mixed with the [`System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function, you could so something like the following: `foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*img01.*")) { File.Delete(file); }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using LINQ and TPL

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp)$");

Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\temp")
         .Where(file => reg.Match(file).Success).AsParallel()
         .ForAll(File.Delete)
```

Or just LINQ

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp)$");

Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\temp")
         .Where(file => reg.Match(file).Success).ToList()
         .ForEach(File.Delete)
```

Comment: Any reason for the AsParallel() here?

Comment: @Moo-Juice to delete faster

Comment: I'd proffer you'd just create contention on the hard-drive doing that.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I provied another way without TPL

Comment: @Moo-Juice if you have a SSD should you still use non-parallel execution?